# PHP get small year from 2015?

Tags: php, date

Hello friends i Want to getting small year from full year like

```
$smallYear = date('y',strtotime('2016'));
// it's return 16

// when i passed 2017
$smallYear = date('y',strtotime('2017'));
// it's return 16 means it's return current date
```

How to get 16 from 2016 and 17 from 2017 using php. below is my full function for generating years.

```
   public static function getYears() {
       $years = array();
       $curYear = date("Y");
       $limit = 16;
       echo date('y',strtotime('2015'));
       for ($x = $curYear; $x < $curYear + $limit; $x++) {
           $xd = date('y',strtotime($x));
           $years[$xd] = $x;
       }
       return $years;
   }
```

I want to set small year as a key. i want output like

```
array(
   '16' => 2016,
   '17' => 2017,
   '18' => 2018,
   '19' => 2019
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
function makeShortYear($theYear) {
   return date('y',strtotime("$theYear-01-01"));
}

echo makeShortYear(2016) . "\n";  // 16
echo makeShortYear(2017) . "\n";  // 17
echo makeShortYear(1998) . "\n";  // 98
?>
```

You did not state your requirements very clearly (two example inputs is not enough to build a full picture of how you wish your program to behave in general), but is [this](https://ideone.com/kPa2Sg) what you meant?

The year 3000 won't work, because `strtotime` is based on 32-bit UNIX timestamps, which don't go that far.

Here's an alternative which [*does*](https://ideone.com/IwqUHf):

```
<?php
function makeShortYear($theYear) {
   return (new DateTime("$theYear-01-01"))->format("y");
}

echo makeShortYear(2016) . "\n";  // 16
echo makeShortYear(2017) . "\n";  // 17
echo makeShortYear(1998) . "\n";  // 98
echo makeShortYear(3000) . "\n";  // 00
echo makeShortYear(3001) . "\n";  // 01
?>
```

In both cases, the key is very simply to provide a full date as input, by adding arbitrary month and day.

Answer (score 1):

**Try the following solution (http://ideone.com/fIv6wS):**

```
function getYears() {
    $years = array();
    $curYear = date("Y");
    $limit = 16;
    echo date('y',strtotime('2015'));

    for ($x = $curYear; $x < $curYear + $limit; $x++) {
        $xd = $x % ((int)($curYear / 1000) * 1000);
        $years[$xd] = $x;
    }
    return $years;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$smallYear = date('d-m-y H:i:s',strtotime('2017'));
```

Doing this will always give your current year because you're passing only **Hours** and **minutes** to `strtotime` method. So you're getting 16 as output instead of 17. Result of this is **29-10-16 20:17:00**

```
$smallYear = date('y',strtotime('+1 year'));
```

This will give you 17 instead or 16, because current year is 16 you're adding + 1 to year so result  is 17. Using this you can build your logic.